# How to get the List Item id when a sharepoint choice column changes?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the JSOM solutions I am working on, I am alerting the SharePoint choice column value upon change. I have a list called Asset List (collaboration list) with four columns: Title, Stage(Choice column with choices: Development, Transition and Property), Asset Link (Hyperlink type column) and Asset Description. Please see below screenshot for reference

[image: Asset List]

So right now using below code I am able to catch and alert when a stage choice column value changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  
$("select[title='Stage']").change(function() {  
        
          var stage = $("select[title='Stage']").val();  
            
alert(stage);       


});
});
</script>
```

Now the next challenging step is when the stage value changes for e.g. from Development to transition then I also want to get the list item id or ID(metadata column value for that change) and the URL value from the Asset Link column.I have to pass either ID or ListItemID and also the URL value into couple of functions so need to capture them when a stage value changes. I am using JSOM and working with office 365/SharePoint online.
If any one has an idea, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get item ID and the URL value of the Asset Link column:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  
$("select[title='Stage']").change(function() {  
    var stage = $("select[title='Stage']").val(); 
    alert(stage);
    var itemID = getParameterByName('ID'); 
    alert(itemID);     
    var URL = $("input[id^='Asset_x0020_Link']").val();
    alert(URL);

});
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

</script>
```

The result is:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {  
 $("select[title='Stage']").change(function() {  
   var itemid = GetUrlKeyValue("ID") 
   var stage = $("select[title='Stage']").val(); 
   var AssetLink = $("input[id^='AssetLink']").val();
     alert("Stage: " + stage + "\n" +  " ID: " + itemid + "\n" + "Asset 
           Link: " + AssetLink); 
});
});
</script>
```