# How to read the ID on a SharePoint list's edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the projects I am working on, I am developing a JSOM solution to do certain things. Part of the solution  I have to read the "ID" that appears on the SharePoint list's edit form (in the browser url). Please see below screenshot.

[image: Edit Form]
As seen in the above screenshot, I want to read that ID value which equals to 4 and based on that value i have to further call other functions. I googled a lot but could not find a way to read that ID. Can someone please help me on this, thanks. I am working with SharePoint/office 365. Please provide code for this using JS or Jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  
    var itemID = getParameterByName('ID'); 
    alert(itemID);     
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

</script>
```

The Result is:
[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch, I almost spent a day digging for this, it worked.

Comment: asking one more help, now that I am capturing the ID, will it be possible to capture the URL portion from the Asset Link hyperlink column by passing the ID? Thanks.

Comment: I have replied your another thread about this similar issue, you can refer to it: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239787/how-to-get-the-list-item-id-when-a-sharepoint-choice-column-changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint's internal utility class to grab information from a query string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
    itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["ID"];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below in script editor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var ID = GetUrlKeyValue('ID');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There should also be an object created by SharePoint on classic forms:
`WPQ1FormCtx.` I have seen this been named WPQ2FormCtx too for some reasons I don't know.

So you could get it like this: `WPQ1FormCtx.ItemAttributes.Id`. There is also alot of other nice props in the object that could be useful.

Guess you could do it like this:

```
(window["WPQ1FormCtx"] || window["WPQ2FormCtx"]).ItemAttributes.Id
```